# Integral values satisfying a inequality

Tags: inequality

Consider the following inequality :

$$\frac{x^2+a^2}{a(4+x)} \ge 1$$

I am trying to find the range of integral values of $a$ for which this inequality holds for all $x$ belongs to $(-1,1)$

I started out by making a quadratic in $a$ but I could not figure out its roots since there was another variable $x$

So can anyone help me figure this out?

Edit : I forgot to mention that $x$ lies in $(-1,1)$

Answer (score 1):

I bet you are looking for the values of $a\in\mathbb{R}^+$ for which
$$ \frac{x^2+a^2}{a(4+x)}\geq 1 $$
holds *for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$*. Well, the solutions of $x^2+a^2 = a(4+x)$ are given by
$$ x = \frac{a\pm\sqrt{16a-3a^2}}{2} $$
provided that $16a-3a^2\geq 0$, so $a=0$ and $a=\frac{16}{3}$ are two critical values.

I leave to you the remaining part.

Comment: @BarryCipra: $-4$ does not belong to $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Answer (score 1):

If $-1\le x\le 1$, then

$${x^2+a^2\over a(4+x)}\ge{0^2+a^2\over a(4+1)}={a\over5}$$

so the inequality is certainly satisfied if $a\ge5$.  At the same time

$${0^2+a^2\over a(4+0)}={a\over4}$$

so the inequality is *not* satisfied if $a\lt4$.  Finally,

$${1^2+4^2\over 4(4+1)}={17\over20}$$

so the inequality is not satisfied if $a=4$.  (Note, this remains true even if we use the *strict* inequality $-1\lt x\lt1$.)  In all, the inequality is true for all integral values of $a$ greater than or equal to $5$.